# "BorderWidth" in Firemonkey

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, delphi-xe5

In VCL Applications there's `BorderWidth` property in `Forms` which is very useful for me. I cannot find this option in `Firemonkey` Applications. If it doesn't exist, what should I use instead of that?

Thanks for your help.

[image: BorderWidth in a VCL Application]

*BorderWidth in a VCL Application*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closest you can get is to use the `Padding` property (also found in the VCL). The main practical difference is that where `BorderWidth` affects the client area coordinates, `Padding` doesn't. E.g., if `ClientWidth` originally read `100` and you set `BorderWidth` to `5`, then `ClientWidth` would become `90` and the width of a top-aligned `TEdit` become `90` too; set `Padding` to `(5, 5, 5, 5)`, and `ClientWidth` will stay `100` even though the `TEdit`'s width will go down to `90`.

That said, be warned that in XE2 and XE3, the `Padding` and `Margins` properties in FMX were mistakenly the wrong way round, so if you're using those versions, it's the `Margins` property to use.